# How to detect when a Cordova WebView completely finished loading?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, webview

I have embedded cordova webview.
and then I have called javascript from native like below.

```
  [self.viewView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: jscode];
```

but it is not performing because JS files were not loaded.

How to detect when a Cordova WebView  completely finished loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the html is loaded, a notification is posted.
You can listen to it with this code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(pageDidLoad) name:CDVPageDidLoadNotification object:self.webView];
```

Then, when the notification is received, the pageDidLoad method will be called, put your code there

```
- (void)pageDidLoad
{
    NSString * jscode = @"some js code here";
   [self.viewView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: jscode];
}
```