# How to detect cordova iOS WebView navigation events

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, cordova, cordova-ios

As per [cordova iOS WebView Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/webview.html) you can embed web views in iOS.

According to that you can do

> `<content src="http://apache.org" />`

with the definition of

> `CDVViewController* viewController = [CDVViewController new];`

I am wondering if there is a way to detect if that content source navigated to another site by clicking the link and if there is way how to get the new URL ?

[CDVViewController](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/master/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVViewController.m) is the one referenced but I can't tell by inspecting as to how one would accomplish that.

A slight parallel to that is Microsoft's `x-ms-webview` which at DOM level allows me to do this:-

> ```
>       var webView = document.getElementByTag("x-ms-webview");
>       webView.addEventListener("MSWebViewNavigationCompleted", function (arg) {
>           if (arg.uri.match(/something)) {
>               doSomething();
>           }
>       });
> ```

Another [example in iOS but just for loading initial page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31263804/how-to-detect-when-a-cordova-webview-completely-finished-loading).

How do detect navigations inside WebView in Cordova iOS ?

Answer (score 2):

Cordova post `CDVPageDidLoadNotification` when the page is loaded.

You can listen for it with

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(pageDidLoad:) name:CDVPageDidLoadNotification object:self.webView];
```

Comment: Does `pageDidLoad` hits navigations ?

Comment: Not really sure what do you mean by that, but pageDidLoad should be called every time a page finish loading

Comment: Will try this. However the case scenario is when a user clicks on a link  inside that webview now the webview displays a different page. If this was a browser the location would change.